# How to get a separate class to read a(n) string array from the main method

Tags: java, arrays, class, program-entry-point

first time doing this but ill try to be brief, currently I am trying to get my code to display names from another class that gets its information from the main method as part of the assignment for my class (confusing I know). basically this is what I have so far:

```
public class Main {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] Names = {
                "Array 1",
                "Array 2",
                "Array 3",
                "Array 4",
                "Array 5",
                "Array (...)",
                "Array 40",
        };



        for (String z : Names)  {
                         //instantiated
            String[] Name = null;

                        //instantiated
            int minutes = 0; 
                        //instantiated
            int seconds = 0; 

            Class1 object = new Class1(Names, minutes, seconds);
            seconds = object .getSeconds();
            minutes = object .getMinutes();
            Name = object .getName(Names);


            System.out.println(Name + ":    " + minutes +" m " + seconds + " s.");
        }

    }

}
```

and this is the separate class:

```
public class Class1{
    private String Name[];
    private double minutes;
    private double seconds;

    public int getMinutes() {
        minutes = Math.random() * 15;
        return (int) this.minutes;
    }

    public int getSeconds() {
        seconds = Math.random() * 59;
        return (int) this.seconds;
    }

    public void setMinutes(int minutes) {
        this.minutes = minutes;
    }

    public void setSeconds(int seconds) {
        this.seconds = seconds;
    }

    public String[] getName(String[] Names) {
        return Names;
    }



    public Song(String[] Names, int minutes, int seconds) {
        this.minutes = getMinutes();
        this.getName(Names);
        this.seconds = getSeconds();
    }
}
```

That's it for my code. Currently the math.random for the seconds and minutes are working perfectly right now but the only this that is eluding me is the Names variable as it is printing out either null or [Ljava.lang.String; on the console. any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You haven't declared a variable `Names` in `Class1` and you are trying to return Names in the method `getName(String[] songNames)`

Comment: return type of method `Song` in `Class1` is not specified.

Comment: yeah just reworked it forgot to edit that part when submitting the coding on the site as well as forgetting to include the private data member for that variable. edited them into the coding

Comment: ill try it but in the next part of my assignment I am required to do a insertion sort within yet another class as well as use an array to store in this case Class1 objects. will this be a problem when constructing the constructer in class1 class?

Comment: should I call the setter within the Song Class or should I just create a new one? Also the for loop is used currently to read one array line at a time ( for (String z : Names) )

Comment: You can declare name as String and not String[]

Answer (score 0):

Add a constructor to `Class1` and from the **constructor** call the **setter methods**.

```
System.out.println(Name + ":    " + minutes +" m " + seconds + " s.");
```

In the above line `Name` is a String array and you can't print it directly using `System.out.println()`.
minutes and seconds wont have decimal places, so you can declare them as `int`.

Comment: everything im trying isn't working. I cant get the setter method to actually set Names as its intended value/string. This is what I put following your instruction:                                                   public Song (String[] Names){
  this.setName(Names);
 }